# .Net MAUI Tabbar not loading when navigating through flyout menu navigation

Tags: .net, mobile-application, maui, .net-maui

I have created flyout navigation and on one of the pages I have a tab bar with multiple tabs, in the first instance landing on HomePage I'm able to navigate between my tabs and once I go away from my Homepage to another page and come back to HomePage content is not loading, its showing blank screen.

AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="LucidUI.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LucidUI"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LucidUI.Views">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
    <FlyoutItem Title="Accounts">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent
                Title="HOME"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}"
                Shell.TitleColor="CadetBlue"
                Shell.BackgroundColor="Black" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Report Settings">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent
                Title="REPORT"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ReportPage}"
                Route="ReportPage"
                Shell.TitleColor="CadetBlue"
                Shell.BackgroundColor="Black" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Referrals" Icon="product_search.png">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent
                Title="Referrals"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ReferralsPage}"
                Route="ReferralsPage"
                Shell.TitleColor="CadetBlue"
                Shell.BackgroundColor="Black" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Logout"></MenuFlyoutItem>
</Shell>
```

HomePage.xaml

```
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LucidUI.Views"
       x:Class="LucidUI.Views.HomePage">
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Clients"
            Icon="cat.png">
            <ShellContent>
                <ContentPage Style="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}">
                    <Frame Background="#fff" Margin="20">
                        <Label Text="Support Text Placement here" />
                    </Frame>
                </ContentPage>
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Scans"
            Icon="cat.png">
            <ShellContent>
                <ContentPage Style="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}">
                    <Frame Background="#fff" Margin="20">
                        <Label Text="Support Text Placement here" />
                    </Frame>
                </ContentPage>
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Products"
            Icon="dog.png">
            <ShellContent>
                <ContentPage Style="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}">
                    <Frame Background="#fff" Margin="20">
                        <Label Text="Support Text Placement here1" />
                    </Frame>
                </ContentPage>
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

Before Navigating to other menu:

[image]

After Navigating coming back on Home:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This potential issue is being tracked on this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9269

**Workaround:**

Here's a workaround that you can use to fix it as suggested by the poster:

**1.** In App.xaml.cs set MainPage to a new Navigation Page with AppShell set as root.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Shell = new AppShell();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(Shell);
}
```

**2.** In AppShell.xaml set the Navigation.TitleView to the custom TitleView.

```
<Shell
    x:Class="ShellNavPageTitleView.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShellNavPageTitleView"
    NavigationPage.TitleView="{StaticResource TitleView}">
    ...
</Shell>
```